# Is [evil-twin] an evil twin of [rogue-ap]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I suspect these two tags might be duplicates?

- [rogue-ap](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rogue-ap): Three questions, all about "fake" copies of Wi-Fi access points.
- [evil-twin](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evil-twin): Seven questions, all about "fake" copies of Wi-Fi access points (except one about SQL-injection and one about a Python library with that name).

No usage guidance for any of them. To me it sounds pretty much like the same thing. Should they be merge, and if so under what name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are different things.

An evil-twin is an AP that clones a legitimate AP in order to try to capture wireless traffic by getting clients to connect to it instead of the genuine AP.

A rouge-ap is an unauthorized AP placed on a wired network, potentially to allow hacking from outside the building, bypassing other physical security measures that protect the network.

That said, two of the questions tagged with rogue-ap are incorrectly tagged.  I have updated them accordingly.